# How can I get the position of the first appearance of a specific term?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Here's the thing, I have the following table:

```
ID       Product       Date
100      AA            2020-02-20
100      BB            2020-03-22
100      CC            2020-02-24
100      CC            2020-04-21
100      AA            2020-01-22
200      CC            2020-02-18
200      DD            2020-03-10
200      EE            2020-05-02
```

Now, I want to get the first time each ID had a product named 'CC' and the position it appeared. For instance, for ID 100, 'CC' appeared for the first time in 2020-02-24, just after AA had appeared twice. For ID 200, 'CC' appeared for the first time in 2020-02-18, and it was the first product. So basically, I would have this output:

```
ID    rank_CC
100   3
200   1
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

One method uses window functions and `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (id) t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as rank
      from t
     ) t
where product = 'CC'
order by id, date;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select id, min(rnk) as rnk
from
(
select id, product,row_number() over(partition by id order by product, date) as rnk
from tablename
)A where product='CC'
group by id
```